# Can we create a Custom login page in Sharepoint foundation 2010?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can we create a Custom login page in Sharepoint foundation 2010? If its possible can you explain how can we done it.

Comment: Did you try _anything_ so far? Also I'm not sure this would be better in [SharePoint.SE] or not.

Comment: we can create Custom Login page in Sharepoint server 2010 but i cant able to create in foundation. i want to know is it possible in foundation?